# Change a future date every five days

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery

I am working on a point of sale app in **Django** in which the customer books a product and it is delivered in 45 days. I can get the delivery date while booking using the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DELIVERY_IN_DAYS = 45

delivery_on = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=DELIVERY_IN_DAYS)
delivery_on = delivery_on.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

now I want the `delivery_on` to remain same for 5 days and change on the 6th day. can I do it without using a background celery job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the "offset" day (the day of the first "change" with five days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can determine a date modulo the number of days with:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()

offset_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
dt = today - offset_date
delivery_on = today + timedelta(days=DELIVERY_IN_DAYS - dt.days % 5)
```

We can wrap the logic into a function:

```
def to_deliver_day(day):
    offset_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
    dt = day - offset_date
    return day + timedelta(days=DELIVERY_IN_DAYS - dt.days % 5)
```

If we call this logic on July 1st until July 10th, we get:

```
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 1))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 13)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 2))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 13)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 3))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 13)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 4))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 5))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 6))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 7))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 8))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 9))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)
>>> to_deliver_day(date(2021, 7, 10))
datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)
```

By setting the `offset_date` differently, you can change the moment when the result makes a "jump"